# javascript Math.cos shows different answer compare to scientific calculator

Tags: javascript

i created a program in javascript that computes vector coordinates, everything was smooth since i have the correct formula, but when i try to conpute for the cosine of 143.1301 using Math.cos in javascript it returns 0.1864 instead of 0.7999 from the scientific calculator why is that? can anyone explain to me why? and also please give me the solution for this problem... thanks in advance... :) here;s a sample of my code

```
function cyltoxec(a)  
{
    ans = Math.cos(a);  
    return ans.toFixed(4);
}
var = x;
return cyltoxec(x);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use `{}` present on the editor window to format your code. You can always have a preview of what it looks like down under the editor window even before posting.

Comment: 0.1864 is in radians, 0.8 is in degrees.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Trigonometric functions in JavaScript (and indeed, in most mathematical parlance and programming) use [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians) as the angular unit, not degrees.

There are `2 * Pi` radians in 360 Degrees. Thus, the cosine of `a` degrees is

```
Math.cos(a * Math.PI/180)
```

Comment: oh thank you! thank you! you save me a lot of trouble there! :)

Answer (score 5):

`Math.cos` expects its argument to be in radians, not degrees.  Try `Math.cos(a * Math.PI/180)` instead.

Comment: you and Adam have the same answer, thank you for the help, im so glad i did not made i mistake asking in this forum, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.  Don't forget to click the checkmark beside Adam's answer to say that you accept it.